# Git-TFS - How to make sure a branch is up to date before pull request is approved?

Tags: git, tfs, branch, git-tfs

I push branch `stav` and create a pull request to `master`. I want to make sure that the pull request can be approved only if branch `stav` contain the last changes from branch `master`.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 14.95.25122.0.

Is it possible? If not, there is a chance that I will create a bug in the system because there won't be any test that will run on the "merged" content between `master` and `stav`.

---

GitHub have this option:
[image]

Comment: At first, I was checking to see if ff-only merge rules (no merge permitted if conflicts exists, among other small changes) were supported in your platform, but it doesn't seem like it is... [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies#merge-requirements). Or perhaps the default option is FF-Only merges? The guide doesn't seem to suggest this, but attempting to enable/disable the checkbox here might yield the kind of result you're looking for... though I honestly doubt it, tbh :(

Comment: No its is not.. I read the same tutorial :( Thanks for looking in to it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if totally got your point. `Make sure that the pull request can be approved only if branch stav contain the last changes from branch master.` What you would like to do is similar to merging the master to stav, then merge stav back to master. This is impossible during a single pull request process in TFS for now.

`Require branches to be up-to-date before merging` If you are talking about the [Enabling required status checks](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-status-checks/) in GitHub. There is no such feature in TFS, you could add a *uservoice* [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.